# reference dll and when to have Copy Local set to true

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio

I have a few separate projects (nothing to do with each other) all of which reference a dll I created, lets call it MyDll.

I have read that by default every project that references my dll will have the Copy Local set to true. So each project has its own copy of MyDll.

What happens though if I rebuild MyDll, will all these copies get updated or do I need to re-add the reference?

Does it make sense to have MyDll in just one place where all my projects reference this file or is this idea unwise?

Comment: I prefer to have this common DLL as source code project in my different projects and handle the updating to these project copies using a souce code version system. Rememeber that if you change this common code then you need to retest everything in the dependent projects. This could be astonishingly costly

Comment: so I would add MyDll project to the solution for each of the projects that use this. What is the main advantage of doing this over adding a reference to the dll?

Comment: Well, the benefits largely depend on the kind of common dll. For example a communication library is allways the same for every project, but an utility library could be very different from project to project. You can fine tune this common dll to the needs of the project. You avoid the need to retest your whole set of projects. (Imagine that you need to ship in an hurry the project to fix a bug but the new version of your library has not been tested against this particular project) In any case I find this to be more flexible. Fundamental here is the role of the versioning system

Comment: MyDll will be the same for each project so sounds more like the communication library example you mention. If I rebuild MyDll does /that mean I would have to rebuild all my projects that reference it

Comment: Then you could add something to your MyDll Post-Build events command line. For example you could call a batch file that copies your recompiled library to the output folders of all your projects. This will ensure that every project will have the latest version of the library and forget the settings of Copy Local.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could add something to the `Post-Build` event (Project->Properties->BuildEvents) of your common dll. For example you could call a batch file that you keep updated with all the output folders of the projects dependent on the dll

```
if /I "$(ConfigurationName)" == "Release" 
         Call $(SolutionDir)\distribute_library.cmd $(TargetPath)
```

(Just one line, splitted here for readability)

Where `distribute_library.cmd` is the batch file containing the commands to copy the `$(TargetPath)` to various destinations.

Something like this:

```
D:
COPY %1 \MyProject1\bin\release
....other targets ....
```

Not to forget: Set the `Run the post-build event`  combo to  `On Successful build`

Answer (score 0):

Copy Local is reference property in project that uses your .dll. 
Process of copying reference assembly into output folder is done when you build your project.
If the path of your reference is set to your project's output folder then you need to rebuild your project.